MoveIt Setup Assistant: The moment i add a gripper, the RVIZ planning marker breaks
i am trying to set up a Kuka robot in Moveit Setup Assistant. (ROS2 Iron, Moveit2)
As soon as i add the last robot links (gripper) in the Planning Groups, the marker used for planning in Rviz is broken (and appears to be at infinity).
Still, in this state, the gripper can be moved around with the mouse and planning actually works.
The marker at infinity issue is independent of if a add a second planning group (gripper) or if i add the gripper links to the arm and only have one group.



Removing the gripper from the Planning Groups, the planning marker is visible.
But not at the gripper's TCP obviously.

But like this, i don't know the frame of the TCP - which i need to do path planning later.
The URDF for the gripper looks like this:
  <!--This frame corresponds to the $TOOL coordinate system in KUKA KRC controllers-->
  <link name="r1_flange"/>
  <joint name="r1_joint_flange" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 3.141592653589793 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="r1_link_6"/>
    <child link="r1_flange"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="r1_tool0"/>
  <joint name="r1_joint_tool0" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="r1_flange"/>
    <child link="r1_tool0"/>
  </joint>
  
  <link name="r1_gripper">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr20r1810_2_description/meshes/gripper/gripper.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr20r1810_2_description/meshes/gripper/gripper.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint name="r1_gripper_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="r1_tool0"/>
    <child link="r1_gripper"/>
    <origin rpy="0 3.141592653589793 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="r1_tcp"/>
  <joint name="r1_gripper_to_tcp" type="fixed">
    <parent link="r1_gripper"/>
    <child link="r1_tcp"/>
    <origin rpy="-2.789145 -0.798060 2.348593" xyz="-0.096459 0.104701 0.299036"/>
  </joint>

I tried so many things already.
As Xacro, as URDF. Connecting the joints to the main arm directly.
The result is always the same: As soon as the gripper is part of the groups, the marker in Rviz is broken.
But i can not get this sorted out.
Please help me.

The issue with the RVIZ planning marker breaking when adding a gripper in MoveIt Setup Assistant is likely due to an incorrect installation of the MoveIt package. To resolve this, you should reinstall the MoveIt package and ensure all dependencies are properly configured. Additionally, verify that the Kuka robot's URDF file does not contain any syntax errors that could cause this behavior. Recompiling the workspace with catkin_make can also help to resolve potential issues related to the planning marker.

Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think reinstalling MoveIt or checking for URDF syntax errors will resolve this specific problem (The URDF was checked when autogenerated from XACRO). The issue seems to be more related to how the gripper is configured within the planning groups or potential transform issues in the URDF.
